# Highcharts PDF export: have the same visual as the PNG export

Tags: highcharts, export

Expected behaviour
When exporting in pdf, i would like to have the same visual as the PNG export
I'm using wkhtmltopdf.

Actual behaviour
When exporting as pdf, labels are not in the box :
[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaE3M.png)

However, exporting as png, everything is okay :
[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StxTd.png)

Is there an option to set ? Or maybe a way to have the same result ?

Live demo with steps to reproduce
Product version
"@highcharts/map-collection": "^1.1.3",
"highcharts": "^9.1.0",

Affected browser(s)
All

Thank you so much for your attention :)

Comment: Could you reproduce your simplified, working code and data in an online editor such as JSFiddle, so that I can also test it? Here you can find a basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t06hvxs8/

Comment: Thank you for your time :)  here it is !

Comment: Sorry, here is the good link https://jsfiddle.net/2xp7t8co/3/#&togetherjs=NsDxCh6dq1

Comment: I would recommend using a dedicated export module supported by highcharts:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting

Then everything works fine when exporting to PDF:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3k2wyxh5/